# How to show a linear transformation is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Considering the $\mathbb{R}$ - Vector space $ V = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and Linear transformations, $H,K \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ ,

$Hf(n) = f(-n)$

$Kf(n) = f(n+1)$

for $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Are $H$ and $K$ diagnonalizable?

I am a little stuck here.

Edit : To diagnonalize a linear map $ F \in Hom(V,V)$ of a K- Vector space means finding a basis for V consisting of eigenvectors of F.

Comment: By $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ do you mean $(a_i)$ where $a_i=0$ for $i>>0$ or just all sequeunces?

Comment: @Chanler all "sequences", and $i$ can also be negative.

Comment: @Sean I'm not quite sure what it means for an endomorphism on a space of uncountable dimension to be "diagonalizable".  It would help if you could clarify what you mean, or provide a definition from your notes or text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvectors of $K$ are the values $\lambda$ such that the equation $K[f] = \lambda f_\lambda$, i.e.
$$
f(n+1) = \lambda f_\lambda(n)
$$
has a non-zero solution $f_\lambda$, and the non-zero solutions $f_\lambda$ are the eigenvectors.

Now, we note that $\lambda = 0$ is *not* an eigenvalue.  For any other value of $\lambda$, suppose that $f(0) = C$.  What we have then is 
$$
f(0) = C\\
f(n + 1) = \lambda f_\lambda(n)\\
f(n) = \frac 1{\lambda} f(n+1)
$$
The unique solution satisfying these conditions is
$$
f_\lambda(n) = C \lambda^n
$$
So, the largest linearly independent set of eigenvectors we can get is the set of all functions
$$
f_\lambda(n) = \lambda^n
$$
for $\lambda \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$.  We note that these functions do *not* form a basis, since there is no (finite!) linear combination of these functions equal to the function
$$
g(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & n = 0\\
0 & n \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
So, $K$ is *not* diagonalizable.

---

The eigenvectors of $H$ are the values $\lambda$ such that the equation $K[f] = \lambda f_\lambda$, i.e.
$$
f(-n) = \lambda f_\lambda(n)
$$
We note that since $H^2$ is the identity function, the only possible eigenvalues of $H$ are $\pm 1$.  In fact, the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 1$ are precisely the even functions, and the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = -1$ are precisely the odd functions.

We note that *any* function $f$ can be written as the sum of an odd function and an even function.  That is, any function $f$ can be written as the linear combination of two eigenvectors of $H$.  It follows that $H$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the eigenvectors of the equation $\lambda K(n)=K(n)=f(n+1)$. We have that $\lambda^N f(n)=f(n+N)$ so that $f(n)/f(n+1)$ is constant. This is not a full basis of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ though, considering sequeunces like $(\dots, 0, 1, 0 \dots)$ this can be shown, so the linear transformation is not diagnol.

On the otherhand $H$ is diagonal. This can be shown as follows. The equation $f=H^2f=\lambda^2f$ implies we should only think of $\lambda=\pm 1$. If $f(n)=Hf(n)=f(-n)$, we call the sequence even and if $-f(n)=Hf(n)=f(-n)$, we call it even. That these eigenvectors form a basis is demonstated as follows. Letting $f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$, then $f(n)=\frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(-n))+\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(-n))$. The first factor is odd, and the latter is even, so we are infact diagonalizable, and the linear transformation is diagonal in this basis.